# issue in printing dictionary value in django

Tags: python, django

I have two list `li_title` and `a_href` as below. I have combined it in to dictionary but it not print any thing in template file.

This is the code in view(value are appended in list with same length):

```py
param = {li_title[i] : a_href[i] for i in range(len(li_title))}
return render(request, 'index.html', param)
```

This is the code in index.html.

```
{% for i,j in param.items %}
    {{j}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: IIRC, `param` needs to be part of a dictionary, otherwise you won't be able to access it by that name.

Comment: @NirmalPatel, I have added an answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using the context properly. `param` is the dictionary that you are passing, and you will be able to use the keys of `param` to access the values. Try using the following code:

```
param = {'param': {li_title[i] : a_href[i] for i in range(len(li_title))}}
```

In this way you will be able to use `param` to access the associated value.

In your template:

```
{% for i,j in param.items %}
    {{j}}
{% endfor %}
```